# Loop's regex conditional doesn't work using extended test

Tags: bash

I have a loop that evaluates based on a regex conditional:

```
until   read -p "Enter oprator: " operator
        [[ $operator =~ ^[+-*\/]$ ]] #doesn't work
do...
```

The loop will run until the user enters an arithmetic operator (+, -, * or /). When I enter any of those four, the loop still runs.

I've tried variations of this (i.e. place regex in variable, using quotes, `grep`) but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[+-*\/]$ ]]$
```

Here problem is placement of an unescaped `-` in the middle of the bracket expression which acts as a range between `+` and `*`.

You may use this regex (no need to escape `/` in BASH regex):

```
[[ $operator =~ ^[-+*/]$ ]]
```

Or even better **without regex** use glob match:

```
[[ $operator == [-+*/] ]]
```

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When including the dash or minus sign `-` in a character class of a Regex, it must be first or last position, or it will be handled like a range marker. Also the slash `/` does not need escaping with a backslash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

until 
  read -r -n1 -p "Enter oprator: " operator
  printf \\n
  [[ "$operator" =~ [+*/-] ]] #doesn't work
do
  printf 'Symbol %q is not an operator!\n' "$operator" >&2
done
```

POSIX shell grammar implementation:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

until
  printf 'Enter oprator: '
  read -r operator
  printf \\n
  [ -n "$operator" ] && [ -z "${operator%%[-+*/]}" ]
do
  printf 'Symbol %s is not an operator!\n' "$operator" >&2
done
```